# Ring and quotient ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let R be a ring and I is an ideal of R.
Can quotient ring R/I has an identity but R does not? I'm having trouble with the example.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should type your question only in English.

Comment: thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Let $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb Z[x]$ of polynomials with *even* constant coefficients. What can you say about the map $p\mapsto p(1)$ ($p\in R$)?

Comment: Hopefully it goes without saying that the linked duplicate is a dupe because of the first isomorphism theorem for rings.

Answer (score 0):

Take $R = \mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$ (addition and multiplication are done componentwise). Then $R$ has no identity. Define $\varphi: R \longrightarrow R$ by $(x, y) \mapsto (x, 0)$. Then $\ker(\varphi) = 0 \times 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $$R/\ker(\varphi) \cong \mathbb{Z}$$ which does have an identity. The idea behind this example is that we take a ring with an identity (such as $\mathbb{Z} \times 0$) and we add more elements (in this case $0 \times 2\mathbb{Z}$) so that what used to be an identity is no longer an identity. Then we quotient out the new elements to get back to the original ring.

Answer (score 0):

Take $R = 2\Bbb Z$ and $I = R$